# Stop, remove, reinstall service in chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I'm writing a chef deploy script for a node.js based web app.  I'm a total chef n00b.

So far, this is going well; I have a "dependencies.rb" recipe which installs all the packages my app relies on.  Right now, I'm trying to write the "install.rb" which will actually go ahead and install my app.

What I want to happen is:

```
If the app install directory already exists then:
    Stop the server
    Delete the old install directory
Unpack the new version to the install directory
Start the service
```

Well, that's a little over simplified, but it's more or less what I'm trying to accomplish.  What's the best way to go about doing this in a recipe?  I have a feeling it's going to involve "notifies".  :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the most part the recipe will match exactly the pseudo-code you've defined in the question. One thing you need to consider however is how you will make the recipe idempotent.

One of the core concepts in Chef is that if the machine is already in the correct state (i.e. you have the correct version of your app deployed already) then you shouldn't perform any work.

While I've not used them you should probably take a look at the [application](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/application) and [application_nodejs](https://github.com/conradev/application_nodejs) cookbooks which expose LWRPs for deploying applications.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers to Application.  I'll have a look at them.

Comment: Although, what I'd REALLY like to do is unpack my app to "myapp-#{version}", symlink "myapp" to that directory, then maybe start the new app on a different port, redirect HAProxy to the new app, then kill off the old app, giving me effectively zero downtime (unless there's a DB migration, of course, in which case kill the old app first, run the migrate, then start the new one.)  Not sure if anything out of the box will be fancy enough to pull that all off.

Comment: Actually, after reading this: http://docs.opscode.com/resource_deploy.html this is going to do almost exactly what I need.  Also I just found https://github.com/RiotGames/artifact-cookbook which also looks useful.